# Dynamically reparenting objects in QML fails on initial load

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to dynamically reparent QML objects generated in a repeater according to data they inherit from their model.

This works like a charm - with one catch. When the object is generated for the first time, it is automatically reparented to the Repeater's parent *after* the state's ParentChange object makes its changes. Run the following QML file in a QML viewer, paying attention to the order of the console messages to see what I'm describing.

After you've clicked on each of the objects, they behave as expected.

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    id: container
    height: 300
    width: 300

    signal completed

    ListModel {
        id: fooModel
        ListElement { data: "red" }
        ListElement { data: "red" }
        ListElement { data: "blue" }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("Rect Completed!")
        container.completed()
    }

    // The object I want to dynamically move
    Component {
        id: delg
        Rectangle {
            id: moveable
            height: 40; width: 100
            border.width: 1; border.color: "black"
            state: model.data
            color: state

            // The following code makes it work, but feels very hackish
            /*Connections {
                target: container
                onCompleted: {
                    moveable.parent = moveable.state == "red" ? red_col : blue_col
                }
            }*/

            onStateChanged: { console.log("New state: " + state) }
            onParentChanged: { console.log("New parent: " + parent) }
            Component.onCompleted: { console.log("Delegate Completed!") }


            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    // I know this is bad to do, but in my REAL application,
                    // the change is triggered through the model, not the qml
                    // object
                    moveable.state = (moveable.state == "red" ? "blue" : "red")
                }
            }

            states: [
                State {
                    name: 'red'
                    ParentChange { target: moveable; parent: red_col; x: 0 }
                },
                State {
                    name: 'blue'
                    ParentChange { target: moveable; parent: blue_col; x: 0 }
                }
            ]

            transitions: [ Transition {
                    ParentAnimation {
                        NumberAnimation { properties: 'x,y,height,width' }
                    }
            }]
        }
    }

    // Generates the Objects
    Repeater {
        id: repeat
        model: fooModel
        delegate: delg
    }

    // Display
    Row {
        spacing: 100
        Column {
            id: red_col
            spacing: 10
            width: 100; height: 300
            move: Transition { NumberAnimation { properties: "y" } }
            add: Transition { NumberAnimation { properties: "y" } }
        }
        Column {
            id: blue_col
            spacing: 10
            width: 100; height: 300
            move: Transition { NumberAnimation { properties: "y" } }
            add: Transition { NumberAnimation { properties: "y" } }
        }
    }

}
```

I figured out a way to fix the behavior, but it's not pretty. (See the commented out "Connections" code above for that fix).

Is there a cleaner/less-hacky way to accomplish the same thing I'm trying here?

Comment: Another way I found to do fix it would be to connect to the repeater's onItemAdded signal (added in QtQuick 1.1) instead. That way would work much better than the commented out suggestion I gave in the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy way of doing it is placing extra `Item` under your delegate. This will cause `Repeater` to reparent `Item` and your own code would set new parent of its child, your `Rectangle` element. Like this:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
Rectangle {
    id: container
    height: 300
    width: 300

    signal completed

    ListModel {
        id: fooModel
        ListElement { data: "red" }
        ListElement { data: "red" }
        ListElement { data: "blue" }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("Rect Completed!")
        container.completed()
    }

    // The object I want to dynamically move
    Component {
        id: delg
        Item { 
            Rectangle {
                id: moveable
                height: 40; width: 100
                border.width: 1; border.color: "black"
                state: model.data
                color: state

                // The following code makes it work, but feels very hackish
                /*Connections {
                    target: container
                    onCompleted: {
                        moveable.parent = moveable.state == "red" ? red_col : blue_col
                    }
                }*/

                onStateChanged: { console.log("New state: " + state) }
                onParentChanged: { console.log("New parent: " + parent) }
                Component.onCompleted: { console.log("Delegate Completed!") }


                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        // I know this is bad to do, but in my REAL application,
                        // the change is triggered through the model, not the qml
                        // object
                        moveable.state = (moveable.state == "red" ? "blue" : "red")
                    }
                }

                states: [
                    State {
                        name: 'red'
                        ParentChange { target: moveable; parent: red_col; x: 0 }
                    },
                    State {
                        name: 'blue'
                        ParentChange { target: moveable; parent: blue_col; x: 0 }
                    }
                ]

                transitions: [ Transition {
                        ParentAnimation {
                            NumberAnimation { properties: 'x,y,height,width' }
                        }
                }]
            }
        }
    }

    // Generates the Objects
    Repeater {
        id: repeat
        model: fooModel
        delegate: delg
    }

    // Display
    Row {
        spacing: 100
        Column {
            id: red_col
            spacing: 10
            width: 100; height: 300
            move: Transition { NumberAnimation { properties: "y" } }
            add: Transition { NumberAnimation { properties: "y" } }
        }
        Column {
            id: blue_col
            spacing: 10
            width: 100; height: 300
            move: Transition { NumberAnimation { properties: "y" } }
            add: Transition { NumberAnimation { properties: "y" } }
        }
    }
}
```